# Why can't I redirect all output to a variable?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, io-redirection

So my understanding of [powershell redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) is that `*>&1` should redirect everything to the output stream.

Try the following from the visual studio package manager terminal on any project with Entity Framework migrations applied.

```
$m = (Get-Migrations *>&1)
```

After running, all your migrations are printed to the window, but `$m` is still `$null`.

What gives? Am I doing redirection wrong?

**Edit:** Seems like maybe I'm not and this should work. [Here is the code for `Get-Migrations`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.PowerShell/Migrations/GetMigrationsCommand.cs)

Comment: What does $m = Get-Migrations give you?

Comment: @Paul it prints out a list of the 20 or so migrations I have applied. Nothing gets stored in `$m`. I've seen this behavior before when using commandline tools which just write directly to the output stream rather than returning powershell objects. I seem to remember that in those cases I used redirection to resolve the issue but its not working here.

Comment: Hmm i see the cmdlet supports common parameters so you could try `-outvariable`

Comment: No dice, same effect with `Get-Migrations -OutVariable m`. Interestingly enough, `Get-Migrations *>$null | Out-Null` **still** outputs results. Shouldn't that always not output anything?

Comment: It seems the commandlet just writes the output to the host, this will not get sent to null as it is not sent through any of the output streams, afaik you won´t be able to get this output into a variable, if you do let me know how :)

Comment: Ugh. [Created an issue on the EF team's board](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2618)

Comment: just thought about it, you could override `write-host` but thats all you can do, its just very bad coding from their side

Comment: You might be able to use `Start-Transcript` instead.

Comment: @Matt, if it did then `*>$null` would not print anything. Redirection isn't working at all. I'll try `Start-Transcript`. Never seen that command before.

Comment: Also, just jaw dropping shock that the EF codebase contains crappy code. /sarcasm

Comment: @Eris no `Start-Transcript`. Visual Studio package manager terminal complains that it does not support transcriptions.

Comment: Suppose you could try to use `Trace-Command` if you really feel up to it. I cant since i dont have access to that type of environment. http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/12/04/trace-your-commands-by-using-trace-command.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`[console]::WriteLine`, which is what `Get-Migrations` is using, is basically the same as `Write-Host`, so it only prints the output and doesn't send anything through the pipeline like `Write-Output` does.

I found a dev named Lincoln Atkinson that has implemented a solution that uses a proxy for `Write-Host` at http://latkin.org/blog/2012/04/25/how-to-capture-or-redirect-write-host-output-in-powershell/

I've tested out his function and it seems to need a little work, it only worked for me when I passed the `-Quiet` flag. It also only works for `Write-Host` so updating it to work with `WriteLine` would be your take-home assignment from this....

Also it looks like while `Start-Transcript` might help (along with a generous parsing of output) if it were `Write-Host` based, but does not appear to catch `[console]::WriteLine` for whatever reason.